# What do I need to sign with my prototype maker before I file a patent?

Tags: patent-infringement

I currently have an idea. First I need to make a prototype.

What do I need to sign with the prototype maker, seamstress, so that it will legally bind her to not steal my idea and not tell anyone about my idea?

Comment: Although building prototypes is an excellent idea, you don't need one to obtain a patent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you need to have is called a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) also called a Confidential Disclosure Agreement (CDA). Basically it binds the parties to not disclose confidential information for a period of time. Typically these are written with two periods. First is a period for disclosure. This might be 1 month or 1 year. Second is a period of confidentiality. This is often something like 5 years which is generally long enough to obtain a patent. If you search on "NDA template free" you will get plenty of examples.

Comment: What about non-compete. Does the NDA prevent the signee from using the idea?

Comment: You can certainly do a non-compete too. I would only work with a prototyper if possible. They don’t last long if they steal their client’s IP.

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages I should point out that if your seamstress goes and makes your invention and sells it, that would constitute public disclosure. You would then have grounds for a law suit.